# kubernetes auth error: impersonation request has been denied, group header value is not allowed in roles

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-rbac

I'm unable to impersonate as group in kubernetes 1.21

```sh
✗  k version                                                                              
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.1", GitCommit:"5e58841cce77d4bc13713ad2b91fa0d961e69192", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T14:18:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.2-eks-0389ca3", GitCommit:"8a4e27b9d88142bbdd21b997b532eb6d493df6d2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-31T01:34:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```sh
✗  k auth can-i --as=dmitry --as-group=system:masters get pods -n argo-cd

Error from server: impersonation request has been denied, user header "dmitry" is not allowed in roles
```

```sh
✗  k auth can-i --as=dmitry --as-group=team:sso:bolrdswp-devops update secrets -n argo-cd 

Error from server: impersonation request has been denied, group header "team:sso:bolrdswp-devops" value is not allowed in roles
```

So how to impersonate as a particular group in kubernetes?

Comment: How did you setup your cluster? What exactly did you deploy inside it?

Comment: via terraform with 
```
source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
version = "17.1.0"
```

Empty cluster + argo-cd.